# Kafka Mirror Maker for same topic name in source and destination cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I want to set up kafka MM2 between source cluster and destination cluster. My use case is I can successfully mirror from source cluster topic "test" to destination cluster topic "test" (without cluster name prefixed).

Now I want mirror from source cluster topic "test" to destination cluster topic "xyx" (without cluster name prefixed). Any leads would be appreciated?

Hi,

I want to set up kafka MM2 between source cluster and destination cluster with different topics name.

Answer (score 0):

MirrorMaker uses a replication policy to determine the name of remote topics. The default replication policy injects the source cluster alias as a prefix to remote topic.

MirrorMaker also has another replication policy that keep the topic names, it called [IdentityReplicationPolicy](https://kafka.apache.org/33/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/mirror/IdentityReplicationPolicy.html).

In order to use it you need to set the `replication.policy.class` setting in your MirrorMaker configuration to `org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.IdentityReplicationPolicy`.

Comment: I have added below properties in mm2 conf at destination end so that source cluster alias does not get prefixed.    replication.policy.separator, source.cluster.alias, destination.cluster.alias is set as blank. Now I want to name destination cluster topic as something different not like source cluster topic name.